# Avoid memory allocation when indexing an array in Julia

Tags: julia

**UPDATE:** Note that the relevant function in Julia v1+ is `view`

**Question:** I would like to index into an array without triggering memory allocation, especially when passing the indexed elements into a function. From reading the Julia docs, I suspect the answer revolves around using the `sub` function, but can't quite see how...

**Working Example:** I build a large vector of `Float64` (`x`) and then an index to every observation in `x`.

```
N = 10000000
x = randn(N)
inds = [1:N]
```

Now I time the `mean` function over `x` and `x[inds]` (I run `mean(randn(2))` first to avoid any compiler irregularities in the timing):

```
@time mean(x)
@time mean(x[inds])
```

It's an identical calculation, but as expected the results of the timings are:

```
elapsed time: 0.007029772 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.067880112 seconds (80000208 bytes allocated, 35.38% gc time)
```

So, is there a way around the memory allocation problem for arbitrary choices of `inds` (and arbitrary choice of array and function)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> EDIT: Read tholy's answer too to get a full picture!

When using an array of indices, the situation is not great right now on Julia 0.4-pre (start of Feb 2015):

```
julia> N = 10000000;
julia> x = randn(N);
julia> inds = [1:N];
julia> @time mean(x)
elapsed time: 0.010702729 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.012167155 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
julia> @time mean(x[inds])
elapsed time: 0.088312275 seconds (76 MB allocated, 17.87% gc time in 1 pauses with 0 full sweep)
elapsed time: 0.073672734 seconds (76 MB allocated, 3.27% gc time in 1 pauses with 0 full sweep)
elapsed time: 0.071646757 seconds (76 MB allocated, 1.08% gc time in 1 pauses with 0 full sweep)
julia> xs = sub(x,inds);  # Only works on 0.4
julia> @time mean(xs)
elapsed time: 0.057446177 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.096983673 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.096711312 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
julia> using ArrayViews
julia> xv = view(x, 1:N)  # Note use of a range, not [1:N]!
julia> @time mean(xv)
elapsed time: 0.012919509 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.013010655 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.01288134 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
julia> xs = sub(x,1:N)  # Works on 0.3 and 0.4
julia> @time mean(xs)
elapsed time: 0.014191482 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.014023089 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.01257188 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
```

- So while we can avoid the memory allocation, we are actually slower(!) still.
- The issue is indexing by an array, as opposed to a range. You can't use `sub` for this on 0.3, but you can on 0.4.
- If we can index by a range, then we can use [ArrayViews.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/ArrayViews.jl) on 0.3 and its inbuilt on 0.4. This case is pretty much as good as the original `mean`.

I noticed that with a smaller number of indices used (instead of the whole range), the gap is much smaller, and the memory allocation is low, so `sub` might be worth:

```
N = 100000000
x = randn(N)
inds = [1:div(N,10)]

@time mean(x)
@time mean(x)
@time mean(x)
@time mean(x[inds])
@time mean(x[inds])
@time mean(x[inds])
xi = sub(x,inds)
@time mean(xi)
@time mean(xi)
@time mean(xi)
```

gives

```
elapsed time: 0.092831612 seconds (985 kB allocated)
elapsed time: 0.067694917 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.066209038 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.066816927 seconds (76 MB allocated, 20.62% gc time in 1 pauses with 1 full sweep)
elapsed time: 0.057211528 seconds (76 MB allocated, 19.57% gc time in 1 pauses with 0 full sweep)
elapsed time: 0.046782848 seconds (76 MB allocated, 1.81% gc time in 1 pauses with 0 full sweep)
elapsed time: 0.186084807 seconds (4 MB allocated)
elapsed time: 0.057476269 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.05733602 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
```

Comment: Very informative (as always). Many thanks. Perhaps it is worth adding that  `sub` does not appear to work for vector indices at all in v0.3.5 (`sub(x, inds)` throws an error on my machine, but works if the second argument to `sub` is a range object)

Comment: Note the distinction between `1:N` and `[1:N]`, see my answer.

Comment: IainDunning, to clarify: where you say "it's not great now, but will be fixed before 0.4 is released," that's simply not true. It's already as well-optimized as computer hardware permits, and when indexing with a range `sub` is just as performant as `view`. There is no way to make indexing with a vector as performant as indexing with a range.

Comment: Hopefully I've fixed my answer so its not actively misleading, can you check?

Comment: Now I understand your remaining concern better. For me, `mean(x[inds])` is always slower---by a pretty large factor, 60-100%---than `mean(sub(x, inds))`. Since it doesn't seem to be for you, can you open an issue?

Comment: See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/10093. Thanks for pursuing this, IainDunning.

Answer (score 16):

Just use `xs = sub(x, 1:N)`. Note that this is different from `x = sub(x, [1:N])`; on julia 0.3 the latter will fail, and on julia 0.4-pre the latter will be considerably slower than the former. On julia 0.4-pre, `sub(x, 1:N)` is just as fast as `view`:

```
julia> N = 10000000;

julia> x = randn(N);

julia> xs = sub(x, 1:N);

julia> using ArrayViews

julia> xv = view(x, 1:N);

julia> mean(x)
-0.0002491126429772525

julia> mean(xs)
-0.0002491126429772525

julia> mean(xv)
-0.0002491126429772525

julia> @time mean(x);
elapsed time: 0.015345806 seconds (27 kB allocated)

julia> @time mean(xs);
elapsed time: 0.013815785 seconds (96 bytes allocated)

julia> @time mean(xv);
elapsed time: 0.015871052 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
```

There are several reasons why `sub(x, inds)` is slower than `sub(x, 1:N)`:

- Each access `xs[i]` corresponds to `x[inds[i]]`; we have to look up two memory locations rather than one
- If `inds` is not in order, you will get poor cache behavior in accessing the elements of `x`
- It destroys the ability to use SIMD vectorization

In this case, the latter is probably the most important effect. This is not a Julia limitation; the same thing would happen were you to write the equivalent code in C, Fortran, or assembly.

Note that it's still faster to say `sum(sub(x, inds))` than `sum(x[inds])`, (until the latter becomes the former, which it should by the time julia 0.4 is officially out). But if you have to do many operations with `xs = sub(x, inds)`, in some circumstances it will be worth your while to make a copy, even though it allocates memory, just so you can take advantage of the optimizations possible when values are stored in contiguous memory.

Comment: This is very interesting. I hadn't considered the advantage inherent in creating a new object in *contiguous* memory. Many thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, to transform array subsetting into index subsetting, is it ever worth it to sort in place, subindex, and then resort in place?