# How to pass a pointer to a subarray with BLAS function?

Tags: pointers, julia

I am using Julia v0.3.5, which comes with WinPython 3.4.2.5 build 4.  I am new to Julia.  I am testing how fast Julia is compared to using SciPy's BLAS wrapper for ddot(), which has the following arguments: x,y,n,offx,incx,offy,incy.  Julia's OpenBLAS library does not have the offset arguments, so I am trying to figure out how to emulate them while maximizing speed.  I am passing 100MB subarrays of a 1GB array (vector) multiple times, so I don't want Julia to create a copy of each subarray, which would reduce the speed.  Python's SciPy function is taking a couple of hours to execute, so would like to optimize Julia's speed.  I have been reading about how Julia 0.4 will offer array views that avoid the unnecessary copy, but I am unclear about how Julia 0.3.5 handles this.

So far, I learned using REPL that the BLAS dot() function conflicts with the method in linalg/matmul.jl.  Therefore, I learned to access it this way:

```
import Base.LinAlg.BLAS
methods(Base.LinAlg.BLAS.dot)
```

From the method display, I see that I can pass pointers to x and y subarrays and thus avoid a copy.  For example:

```
x = [1., 2., 3.]
y = [4., 5., 6.]
Base.LinAlg.BLAS.dot(2, pointer(x), 1, pointer(y), 1)
```

However, when I add an integer offset to a pointer (to access a subarray), REPL crashes.

How can I pass a pointer to a subarray or a subarray to `Base.LinAlg.BLAS.dot` without the slowdown of a copy of that subarray?
Anything else I missed?

Comment: The conflict warning occurred because I did this: `using Base.LinAlg.BLAS` I now know that I can just call `BLAS.dot()` directly, and `methods(BLAS.dot)` works too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It segfaults because pointer arithmatic doesn't work like you probably think it does (i.e. the C way). `pointer(x)+1` is one byte after `pointer(x)`, but you probably want `pointer(x)+8`, e.g.

```
Base.LinAlg.BLAS.dot(2, pointer(x)+1*sizeof(Float64), 1, pointer(y)+1*sizeof(Float64), 1)
```

or, more user friendly and recommended:

```
Base.LinAlg.dot(x,2:3,y,2:3)
```

which is [defined here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/cb09d285e0f8dcfc1d34e963bf8ddb35c2b5679c/base/linalg/matmul.jl#L43-L49).

I'd say using pointers like that in Julia is really not recommended, but I imagine if you are doing this at all then it is a special circumstance.

Comment: For these large subarrays, the bounds-checking overhead of the standard libarary is insignificant.  I see that the more user-friendly and recommended method is listed when I enter methods(dot) in REPL, but it is not included in the documentation for the standard library.  This has helped me learn how to go beyond the documentation.

Comment: Cool, yeah some things aren't really exposed. `methods` is a great way tool. Speaking of bounds checking, have you read about `@inbounds`?

Comment: `@inbounds` looks useful for smaller subarrays where bounds checking overhead would be significant.  Thanks.  Does Julia v0.3.5 support array views without a copy: `dot(x[2:3], y[2:3])` ?

Comment: Sort-of, you have to explicitly state that you want a subarray: `dot(sub(x, 2:3), sub(y, 2:3))`

Comment: [ArrayViews](https://github.com/JuliaLang/ArrayViews.jl) was introduced, I think, to provide the functionality of `sub()` without the copy.  In Julia v0.3.5, does `sub()` create a copy?  In other words, was ArrayViews merged with the master before the release of v0.3.5?  Or do I need to wait for v0.4 for that?

Comment: `sub` doesn't create a copy, as you can see using `@time`. Please see my answer here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271308/avoid-memory-allocation-when-indexing-an-array-in-julia/28271440#28271440

Comment: My test of Julia 0.3.5 shows that sub() does not do bounds checking for if the end of the range exceeds the array end.  dot() treats treats the undefined values like zeros.  This could be handy in some situations and unexpected in others.  If I take advantage of this, I risk that bounds checking will be added in a future Julia version.  The dot(x,rx,y,ry) method seems the safe and future-compatible way to go.

Comment: Bounds checking on `sub` is a planned feature, so yes it will change.